# sbt auto-plugins - disable them but for one sub project

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

Switching [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) from 0.11.2 to 0.13.0, I suddenly find myself in a situation where calling `sbt assembly` does not just invoke the task in the sub-project that explicitly added `assemblySettings`, but it tries to run it for each and every sub project.

So, if I have

```
lazy val root = project(...).aggregate(core, app)

lazy val core = project(...)

lazy val app  = project(...).dependsOn(core)
```

How can I disable the assembly task for all but the `root` project? With other plugins such as [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) this problem doesn't occur because you have to explicitly enable the plugin per sub-project.

The goal is to be able to run `sbt assembly` so it will do that just for the root project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in a [closed issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/147). You have to add the following line to your common settings:

```
aggregate in assembly := false
```